# How to query the dense vector field in elasticsearch with python client?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, vector

This is the first time time I am using ElasticSearch and Python Client. I am little confused about setting up the query_body to query a dense vector field. Here are the steps I have done so far. Please help me create the query body that I can use in my search function.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util

embedder = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')

with open('my_folder/my_docs.json', 'r') as file:
    documents = json.load(file)

#STEP 1: Embedding documents

for d in documents:
    d['vector']= embedder.encode(d['content'], convert_to_tensor=True) 
    d['vector'] = d['vector'].numpy()

#STEP 2: Defining Mapping Dictionary

mapping = {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text" 
            },
            "content": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "doc_vector": {
                "type": "dense_vector",
                "dims": 768
            }
        }
    }
}

#STEP 3: Creating the Client

client = Elasticsearch("http://localhost:9200")

# STEP 4: Creating Index

response = client.indices.create(
    index="my_doc_dense_index",
    body=mapping,
    ignore=400 # ignore 400 already exists code
)

# STEP 5: Bulk Uploading docs to Index

resp = helpers.bulk(
    client,
    documents,
    index = 'my_doc_dense_index')


#STEP 6: Example Query
query = 'Who is the tennis champion in women''s tennis?'

#STEP 7: Encoding Query
encoded_query = embedder.encode([query])

#STEP 8: Setting up query body with encoded query
query_body = ???????

#STEP 9: submit a search query to ElasticSearch

docs = client.search(body = query_body, index="my_doc_dense_index", size=10)
```

All code from Step 1 through Step 7 are working good. I need help in constructing Step 8 for dense vector query so that I can use it in Step 9. Can some body help.

Thanks in advance,
Kay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `knn` option passing a query object with a `dense_vector` in the `search` or `knn_search` methods.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()
my_vector = [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]

query_string = {
    "field": "my_dense_vector_field",
    "query_vector": my_vector,
    "k": 10,
    "num_candidates": 100
}

# run the query
results = es.search(index="my_index", knn=query_string)
```

See the ES official docs for [search](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search) and [knn_search](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.knn_search)

Comment: Hi Sebastian,   Thanks for your help. But I get a TypeError . I have Python Elastic Search Client version 7.16.1 
   TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'knn'

Comment: Looking at the documentation it doesn't look like the ES client v7.16.1 supports knn search. I am looking at the docs here https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.16.1/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search

Would it be possible to update?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I thought they would have cosine similarity in Version 7.16.1. I am able to add dense vectors, but I am not able query on that. How come? :-)